# jUnit Unexpected method call DAO Easymock

Tags: java, mocking, tdd, dao, easymock

I am newbie with mock testing.
I want to test my DAO for users. Here is my code.

```
private UserService service;
private UserDAO mockDAO;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    service=new UserService();
    mockDAO=createMock(UserDAO.class);
    service.setUserDao(mockDAO);
}

@Test
public void testAddUser(){

    mockDAO.addUser( (User) EasyMock.anyObject());
    EasyMock.replay(mockDAO);
    User u=new User();
    u.setUserName("x");
    u.setPass("y");
    service.registration(u);
    EasyMock.verify(mockDAO);

}
```

When I run it I get this error:

Updated the stacktrace:

```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call  UserDAO.checkUser(si.soa.rentacar.model.User@3655dba1):
  UserDao.addUser(<any>): expected: 1, actual: 0
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
at si.soa.rentacar.dao.UserDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a06d4a9.checkUser(<generated>)
at si.soa.rentacar.ws.impl.UserService.registration(UserService.java:117)
at si.soa.rentacar._testUser.testAddUser(_testUser.java:58)
     ....
```

Comment: your UserService#registration method calls UserDAO#checkUser method, so you need to add it to expectation list

Comment: @hoaz  So what exactly is expectation list? Can you give a clue?

Comment: please check javadoc for EasyMock.expectLastCall() or EasyMock.expect()

Comment: Do you have any example how should I use this methods with DAO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UserService#registration` method calls `UserDAO#checkUser` method, so you need to add it to expectation list. I don't know its parameters, so I am providing you only sample for addUser call below:

```
@Test
public void testAddUser(){

    // prepare data
    User u = new User();
    u.setUserName("x");
    u.setPass("y");

    // expectation section
    mockDAO.addUser(u);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    EasyMock.expect(mockDAO.checkUser(u)).andReturn(true);

    EasyMock.replay(mockDAO);

    // scenario
    service.registration(u);

    // verification
    EasyMock.verify(mockDAO);

}
```

Comment: I have added this method but it is stil ` Unexpected method call`.

Comment: you need to add it for `addUser` call too as I mentioned above

Comment: Yes I did it the same as it is above.

Comment: I think you have not updated code, anyway I guessed parameters and updated my solution

Comment: Now I have update but now I get this error in test: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
UserDAO.checkUser(si.soa.rentacar.model.User@78bc6d6a) Usage is:expect(a.foo()).andXXX()

`

Comment: ok, your method has return value, so you need to use `expect` instead of `expectLastCall`: EasyMock.expect(mockDAO.checkUser(u)).andReturn(true);

Comment: I finally put it to work. If I have login to test, then should I use `assertTrue(service.login(u));`?
 Thank for help.

Comment: yes, i would also cover fail scenario, when login returns false